# iOS WebRTC, horizontal black background displayed behind video

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc, getusermedia, ios15

This is local media stream on iOS 15(iPhone). This wasn't happened before iOS 15.

[image]

When I rotate phone, It fits in black area.

[image]

I tested it at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/

The question is, How can I hide black background on portrait mode?
I want it to be transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known regression:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229792
The fix has already landed in webkit.